# How to clone data that has self relational/ self reference in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-6

How to replicate/clone all data in a table that has self-relation in Laravel?

I have this table:

*members table*

| id | member_id | company_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 23 | John |
| 2 | 1 | 23 | James |
| 3 | 1 | 23 | Ken |
| 4 | null | 23 | Test |
| 5 | 3 | 23 | Max |

**EXISTING CODE**

And I want to replicate all data that has `company_id` of `23` using

```
$members = Members::where['company_id' => 23]->get();
foreach ($members as $member) {
   $duplicate = $member->replicate()->fill(['company_id' => 24);
   $duplicate->save();
}
```

**Results of the code**

*members table*

| id | member_id | company_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 23 | John |
| 2 | 1 | 23 | James |
| 3 | 1 | 23 | Ken |
| 4 | null | 23 | Test |
| 5 | 3 | 23 | Max |
| 6 | null | 24 | John |
| 7 | 1 | 24 | James |
| 8 | 1 | 24 | Ken |
| 9 | null | 24 | Test |
| 10 | 3 | 24 | Max |

But in that code, the replication of self-relation is wrong. How can I do it?

**Expected result**

*members table*

| id | member_id | company_id | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | null | 23 | John |
| 2 | 1 | 23 | James |
| 3 | 1 | 23 | Ken |
| 4 | null | 23 | Test |
| 5 | 3 | 23 | Max |
| 6 | null | 24 | John |
| 7 | 6 | 24 | James |
| 8 | 6 | 24 | Ken |
| 9 | null | 24 | Test |
| 10 | 8 | 24 | Max |

I'm sorry if my English is messed up, but I hope you get the idea of what I'm trying to do. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnLobo sorry I just added the results of the current code. There's no error in the existing code, it just the result of the code is not what I am trying to do.

Comment: yes got it now its updated with expected result

Answer (score 1):

Try this .You have two options to replicate

```
$members = Members::where(['company_id' => 23])->get();
foreach ($members as $member) {
   
    $duplicate = $member->replicate();
    $duplicate->company_id=24;
    $duplicate->save();
}
});
```

or

```
$members = Members::where(['company_id' => 23])->get();
    foreach ($members as $member) {
        
        $duplicate = $member->replicate()->fill(['company_id'=>24]);
       
        $duplicate->save();
    }
    });
```

**Updated**

```
$members = Members::where(['company_id' => 23])->get();
    $tempIdMap=[];
    foreach ($members as $key=>$member) {
        if($key==0){
          $tempIdMap[$member->id]=$member->member_id;
         }
        $duplicate = $member->replicate()->fill(['company_id'=>24,'member_id'=>isset( $tempIdMap[$member->member_id])? $tempIdMap[$member->member_id]:null]);

        $duplicate->save();

        $tempIdMap[$member->id]=$duplicate->id;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately, that's not what I'm trying to do.

Comment: i have updated answer.if any issues let me know i havent tested.

Comment: @Karl. i have verified it .it works as expected result.if any issue let me know.also changed code again

Comment: I tried it and it worked but it got the wrong output if the first record of member has a ```member_id```. Try it for example: id=1, member_id=3, company_id=23, name=John

Comment: let me try it once

Comment: if($key==0){
          $tempIdMap[$member->member_id]=$member->member_id;
         }

Comment: but this will add 3 to first because value should be predictable or else code cant assume.so difficult on that scenario